# Has anyone used an SVN client with Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I know it's pre-release software and that not everything will work, but I wan't to try it out with a couple of projects I have in my SVN repository.

I know I can use a tortoise svn and some other external SVN clients, but I'm looking more for something like RocketSVN that will work inside of Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview...

Answer (score 1):

The latest builds of AnkhSVN include Visual Studio 11 support, haven't tried it though.

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&dsMessageId=428381